# XeLaTeX, Modern Latin and cyrilic

Tags: fonts, xetex, tex-core, fontspec

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!
Привет, мир!
$ a≡b≠Ω♯$
\end{document}
```

Here is example, that do not work. Math -- perfect, but no cyrillic in normal mode. What have I missed?

Comment: It is called **Latin** Modern, of course it has no Cyrillic support.

Comment: I need font that use latex with babel by default. What I have to do?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I extended this question to OSX here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205639/15504 where the *Latin Modern Math* font has been depreciated in MacTeX 2015 causing some compability problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need text font with Cyrillic support, if you want a Computer Modern derivative, try CM Unicode fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!
Привет, мир!
$ a≡b≠Ω♯$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use unicode like ≠ in normal text, unlike with DejaVu font. Well, price of compability.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode) the best place to get the Computer Modern Unicode fonts from.